# Overflow check for static_cast in c++

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

I am using a function for debug builds in a C++ project that wraps static_cast adds checks. It's meant to work for any arithmetic conversions and looks like this:

```cpp
template <typename To, typename From>
inline To as(From f) {
#ifdef NDEBUG
    return static_cast<To>(f);
#else
    To t = static_cast<To>(f);
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<To>::value, "Output type is not arithmetic.");
    static_assert(std::is_arithmetic<From>::value, "Input type is not arithmetic.");
    assert( f == static_cast<From>( t ) );
    assert((From() < f) == (To() < t));
    return t;
#endif
}
```

This works fine for checking if the exact same value is the result of the static_cast but will obviously not work for converting doubles to float as they result in an accuracy loss and thus different number. Since only overflow situations are meant to be seen as an error this should not result in an assert.

My idea was to replace the check with a truncation:

```cpp
assert(std::trunc(f) == std::trunc(t));
```

From my understanding it should work as long as the type isn't more accurate than double but since I haven't found anything similar to it I wanted to make sure. My question thus is whether my checks make sense or if they will fail terribly in some situations I did not think of. I am aware of the std::in_range function in C++20 but that is not an option for me yet.

Comment: I edited the post, but I meant that as in only overflow situations are meant to be seen as an error. All losses in accuracy are fine.

Comment: Well the function is meant to work for all arithmetic types so unless I am seriously misunderstanding something overflow can happen with floating number types like going from double->float?

Comment: Just curious. What is the sense of ```From()``` and ```To()``` and how are supposed to work as long as they are defined as typename ```<typename To, typename From>```?

Comment: @Jundarer There are things called "overflow" and "underflow" for floating point, but those result in a loss of accuracy. If you don't care about loss of accuracy, you can simply limit your checks to when casting to integer types.

Comment: Ok thanks for clearing that up about the range, I was misunderstanding that part. This should allow me to use the "easier" checks as you have pointed out.

Comment: As far as I understand, the behavior of cast of out of range value is unspecified. So a more portable solution would probably use numeric limits. Having said that, you probably want some specializations or `if constexp` statement as the required checks depend on both type. In the easier case like from an `int` to a `long`, you can simply return the value.